# Close Search box when clicking anywhere else

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-4

I'm looking to close my search box when a user clicks on anything else other than my search bar. I've tried a few solutions on stack overflow but they don't seem to work with my implementation.

```js
  $( document ).ready(function() {
      $('[data-toggle=search-form]').click(function(event) {
         event.stopPropagation();
        $('.search-form-wrapper').toggleClass('open');
      });

    $('.search-close, body').click(function(event) {
      if($('.search-form-wrapper').hasClass('open')) {
        $('.search-form-wrapper').removeClass('open');
        $('html').removeClass('search-form-open');
      }
    });
  });
```

```css
.search-form-wrapper {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top:100px;
    left:0;
   width:100%;
   margin:0px;
    z-index: 9998;
}

.search-form-wrapper.open {
    display: block;
}

.search-form-wrapper .search-bar input
{
 height: 41px;
 width:100%;
 border-radius: 0px;
 -webkit-appearance: none;
  border:0px;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #dddcde;
 background: rgba(255,255,255,1);
  padding-left: 45px;
 line-height: 39px;
 -webkit-transition: background .4s;
 transition: background .4s;
 font-family: system-ui;
}

.search-form-wrapper .search-bar .material-icons
{
 height: 70px;
  line-height: 70px;
}


.search-form-wrapper .search-bar input:focus
{
 background: rgba(255,255,255,1);
  outline-width: 0;
}

.search-form-wrapper .search-bar input:focus + .active
{
 color:#4B2058;
}

.search-form-wrapper .search-bar input::placeholder
{
 color:#ffffff8c;
 font-size:15px;
}


.search-form-wrapper .search-bar label {
 top:0;
 left:12px;
 position: absolute;
 color: #45136A;
 -webkit-transition: color .4s;
 transition: color .4s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <nav id="topNav" class="navbar fixed-to navbar-expand-md">
      <a class="navbar-brand mx-auto" href="/">
          <img src="{{ siteUrl }}/img/logo.svg" alt="Go to Ticketstoday Homepage"/>
      </a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
          Menu
      </button>
      <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="navbar-nav">
              <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link menu-btn" href="#"><span class="material-icons">menu</span>Browse</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#" data-toggle="search-form"><span class="material-icons">search</span>Search</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#"><span class="material-icons">favorite_border</span>Top 50</a>
              </li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">

              <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
              </li>

              <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Join</a>
              </li>

          </ul>
      </div>
  </nav>
  
<div class="search-form-wrapper">
    <form action="{{ url('search/results') }}" class="search-bar" autocomplete="off" itemprop="potentialAction" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/SearchAction">
        <meta itemprop="target" content="{{ siteUrl }}/search/results?q={search_term_string}"/>
        <input id="search" itemprop="query-input" type="search" aria-label="Search" name="q" placeholder="Search for Coupons, Stores & Deals" class="browser-default">
        <label for="search"><i class="material-icons">search</i></label>
        <span class="input-group-addon search-close" id="basic-addon2"><i class="fa fa-window-close" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </form>
  </div>
```

Added Snippet above instead of just the code, hopefully this will help us solve the problem - as you can see, when clicking on the search bar when it's open - it closes the search box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply attach the click event on the `<body>` too, **note that I'm passing my `event` to the callback and using `event.stopPropagation();` to prevent event on document body from being fired.**

something like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  const searchForm = $("#search").get(0);
  $("[data-toggle=search-form]").click(function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    $(".search-form-wrapper").toggleClass("open");
  });

  $(".search-close, body").click(function (event) {
    if (event.target !== searchForm) {
      $(".search-form-wrapper").removeClass("open");
      $("html").removeClass("search-form-open");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.search-form-wrapper {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  z-index: 9998;
}

.search-form-wrapper.open {
  display: block;
}

.search-form-wrapper .search-bar input {
  height: 41px;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 0px;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  border: 0px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dddcde;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  padding-left: 45px;
  line-height: 39px;
  -webkit-transition: background .4s;
  transition: background .4s;
  font-family: system-ui;
}

.search-form-wrapper .search-bar .material-icons {
  height: 70px;
  line-height: 70px;
}

.search-form-wrapper .search-bar input:focus {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  outline-width: 0;
}

.search-form-wrapper .search-bar input:focus+.active {
  color: #4B2058;
}

.search-form-wrapper .search-bar input::placeholder {
  color: #ffffff8c;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.search-form-wrapper .search-bar label {
  top: 0;
  left: 12px;
  position: absolute;
  color: #45136A;
  -webkit-transition: color .4s;
  transition: color .4s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <nav id="topNav" class="navbar fixed-to navbar-expand-md">
      <a class="navbar-brand mx-auto" href="/">
          <img src="{{ siteUrl }}/img/logo.svg" alt="Go to Ticketstoday Homepage"/>
      </a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
          Menu
      </button>
      <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="navbar-nav">
              <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link menu-btn" href="#"><span class="material-icons">menu</span>Browse</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#" data-toggle="search-form"><span class="material-icons">search</span>Search</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#"><span class="material-icons">favorite_border</span>Top 50</a>
              </li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">

              <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
              </li>

              <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Join</a>
              </li>

          </ul>
      </div>
  </nav>
  
<div class="search-form-wrapper">
    <form action="{{ url('search/results') }}" class="search-bar" autocomplete="off" itemprop="potentialAction" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/SearchAction">
        <meta itemprop="target" content="{{ siteUrl }}/search/results?q={search_term_string}"/>
        <input id="search" itemprop="query-input" type="search" aria-label="Search" name="q" placeholder="Search for Coupons, Stores & Deals" class="browser-default">
        <label for="search"><i class="material-icons">search</i></label>
        <span class="input-group-addon search-close" id="basic-addon2"><i class="fa fa-window-close" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </form>
  </div>
```

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  const searchForm = $("#search").get(0);
  $("[data-toggle=search-form]").click(function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    $(".search-form-wrapper").toggleClass("open");
  });

  $(".search-close, body").click(function (event) {
    if (event.target !== searchForm) {
      $(".search-form-wrapper").removeClass("open");
      $("html").removeClass("search-form-open");
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Hmm, this seems to not open the search form at all?

Comment: @JMKelley, at least this should not affect the open functionality, did you get any js errors in developer tools console?

Comment: Nope - nothing. I'll add the HTML to the question.

Comment: @JMKelley, I updated my answer, please check it now.

Comment: Ah, when trying to type in the search bar it closes :S

Comment: can you add the CSS and html wrapper in a snippet or [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: Added Snippet to the question

Comment: @JMKelley, I fixed it, just had to check for the target element being clicked. let me know if you still have issues :)